# Is it possible to run each testcase in a separate process?

Tags: c++, googletest

Is it possible to run each testcase in a separate process other than a single process?

[It seems that `gtest` itself does not intend to support this feature.](https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/72)

As I did a test and I found all the testcases are run in the same thread. Here is the said code snippet:

```
TEST(TestSuitNameA, TestCaseName)
{
  std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
}

TEST(TestSuitNameB, TestCaseName)
{
  std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want each test cases to run in a separate process? Test cases should not depend on other test cases

Comment: @Asesh Because some Apis which are provided by others influence the global variable(which is out of my control). When each testcase is run in a separate process, I don't not have to worry about it anymore.

Comment: You could write a script yourself that first lists all the tests and then executes them individually. Actually quite similar to what [gtest-parallel](https://github.com/google/gtest-parallel) would do when you specify as many cores as there are tests, except that it would probably block your system if thousands of processes compete for the same few actually available cores.

Comment: @Sedenion Is it possible to achieve this goal with some mature tools, say `CTest`?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have personal experience with CTest, but if I read the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GoogleTest.html) correctly, `gtest_discover_tests` is already doing almost what you want: one process per test case (but not per test).

Comment: @Sedenion I did some tests with `gtest_discover_tests ` and find you are right. It really could achieve my goal. But I can't see that the aforementioned page has said anything about that(i.e. one process per test case), could you please point out that to me?

Comment: It is stated indirectly. Quote from [the page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GoogleTest.html): "Note that this is in some cases less efficient, as common set-up and tear-down logic cannot be shared by multiple test cases executing in the same instance." I.e. the setup code (e.g. in `main`) is executed for every test case, meaning separate processes for every test case are being used.

Comment: Also, from the same page: "will create a separate CTest test for each Google Test test case". And on [another page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_test.html#command:add_test): "The given test command is expected to exit with code 0 to pass and non-zero to fail". Again implying separate processes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a hack that you can use: force each test to die at the end.

Say you want to test a function called `MyFunction`, you can then wrap it in another function called `MyFunctionTester` which exits with code 0 if the test passes and 1 otherwise. Then in your test, use `EXPECT_EXIT`.

Here is a quick example:

```cpp
int MyFunction(int a){
    return a+1;
}

void MyFunctionTester(int a){
    auto actual = MyFunction(a);
    std::cout << "actual: " << actual << std::endl;
    _exit(actual);
}

TEST(TestSuitNameA, TestCaseName)
{
  GTEST_FLAG_SET(death_test_style, "threadsafe");
  std::cout << "  thread id: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
  EXPECT_EXIT(MyFunctionTester(1), testing::ExitedWithCode(2), "");
}

TEST(TestSuitNameB, TestCaseName)
{
  GTEST_FLAG_SET(death_test_style, "threadsafe");
  std::cout << "  thread id: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
  EXPECT_EXIT(MyFunctionTester(2), testing::ExitedWithCode(3), "");
}
```

Live example here: https://godbolt.org/z/WrWz67jhG

Please notice that this is really a hack and far from ideal, but it seems to work.

See [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#death-tests-and-threads) for more info on death tests.